# Are there any risks of referencing the variable that's being created?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I normally do:

```
var x; 
x = new Slider({
    'dragstart' : function(e,ui){
        // blablabla
        x.addClass('being-dragged'); // using X here.
        // blablabla 
    }
});
```

Instead, should I be confident to do

```
var x = new Slider({
    'dragstart' : function(e,ui){
        // blablabla
        x.addClass('being-dragged'); // using X here.
        // blablabla 
    }
});
```

The way I see things, `x` doesn't exist in the local scope when that function is being constructed, so I keep worrying it might pick another `x` from global, window or wherever it finds it.

Comment: Your snippets are exactly equivalent due to hoisting. Btw, it wouldn't even matter if a new variable would be added to the scope after you did create drag handler function, it still would be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `x` doesn't exist in the local scope when that function is being constructed

The `dragstart` function does not get "constructed" until it is invoked. If `x` is `undefined` at the time of that invocation, it will fail. The only way `x` will be `undefined` at that time is if the `dragstart` function is called from the `Slider` constructor (in which case the constructor has not returned the instance, so `x` still has its default value which is implicitly `undefined`).

Otherwise, when `dragstart` is invoked the reference to `x` will resolve to the `x` in the outer scope as you expect.